# How do I include an environment variable inside an alias for bash?

Tags: bash

I am pretty new to bash, and I want to include an env for bash aliases.. I want to do something like the following

```
alias foo="bar $(baz)"
```

So that I could do something like the following

```
> baz=40
> foo
```

and foo will expand to the command `bar 40`. Currently the above does not work because $(baz) is expanded while making the alias. Do I have to wrap this inside a function or something?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to use single quotes (`'`) to prevent bash from expanding the variable when creating the alias:

```
$ alias foo='echo "$bar"'
$ bar="hello"
$ foo
hello
```

Comment: Also `alias test=echo \$bar` (same idea, expansion is suppressed)

Comment: Correct answer, just be careful aliasing `test`, it is an actual command.

Comment: `alias foo='echo "$bar"'`. The `export` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 12):

Aliases don't have an "environment". In the question, an environment variable isn't being used - only a shell variable. If you want to use the environment, use a function. In this case, there is no advantage to an alias over a function.

```
$ alias foo='echo "$bar"'
$ bar=hi foo
```

This produces no output because assignments are evaluated after word expansions.

```
$ alias foo=$'eval \'echo "$bar"\''
$ bar=hi foo
hi
```

**Edit**

```
function f {
    typeset -n ref=$1
    printf '%s\n' "$ref"
}

foo=moo command -- \
    eval -- \
    typeset +x foo \; f foo
```

Answer (score 5):

I do the following to delay expansion of environment variables in aliases until they are run,

```
alias foo="ls \${FOO_DIR}"
```

for example to show the contents of the dynamically-defined value of `FOO_DIR`.

Comment: this should be the top answer bc it is the most flexible method (great when you need double quotes around the alias, which is frequently for me, because i use JQ a lot)

Comment: This will be a complete answer if you will include a usage example (how you pass a variable when you call a command).

Comment: @Nairum It runs `ls` with whatever `$FOO_DIR` expands to. There is no argument (passed on the command line to the command).