# Git Bash: Trying to assign current branch to variable in .bashrc alias script, but variable remains empty

Tags: bash, git, shell, alias, git-bash

I am trying to register a script alias in my `.bashrc` for easy switching from the current branch to master, pulling, switching back to the branch, and rebasing.

Currently, my alias script looks like this:

```bash
alias gmm="branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);
echo \"Switching from '$branch' to 'master'\";
git checkout master;
git pull;
echo \"Switching from 'master' to '$branch'\";
git checkout $branch;
git rebase master"
```

However, the current branch does not seem to be saved to the `branch` variable, and the command prints the following:

```console
Mai@DESKTOP-M71G3R MINGW64 /c/dev/git/myrepo (testing)
$ gmm
Switching from '' to 'master'
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported
Already up to date.
Switching from 'master' to ''
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

I have already checked that the command itself indeed gets the current branch name:

```console
Mai@DESKTOP-M71G3R MINGW64 /c/dev/git/myrepo (testing)
$ branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

Mai@DESKTOP-M71G3R MINGW64 /c/dev/git/myrepo (testing)
$ echo $branch
testing
```

I've spent days googling but I can't figure out where and why the variable assignment fails.

Comment: The `git` command is executed at the time where .bashrc is sourced, and of course you don't have a branch at that time. Either turn your `alias` into a function, or escape the `$`.

Comment: Why don't you run `git pull --rebase origin master` while on your branch (and maybe put that into a Git alias: `git config --global alias.pm 'pull --rebase origin master'`)? Switching branches can be quite expensive if your only goal is to update the local ref

Comment: @knittl You have a very valid point. For only rebasing my current branch with the remote master, that is indeed the more efficient idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use single quotes for alias content as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172247/14967413). When using double quotes, `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` will resolve as early as `.bashrc` is executed and will probably become empty string. If you use single quotes instead, `$(git rev-parse...)` will resolve when `gmm` is run, which means it correctly becomes current branch's name.

```
alias gmm='branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);
echo "Switching from '\''$branch'\'' to master";
git checkout master;
git pull;
echo "Switching from master to '\''$branch'\'';
git checkout "$branch";
git rebase master'
```

Preferably I would use bash function instead of alias, which is more convenient.

```
gmm() {
  local branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD);
  echo "Switching from $branch to master";
  git checkout master;
  git pull;
  echo "Switching from master to $branch";
  git checkout "$branch";
  git rebase master
}
```

Comment: You have new quoting errors in the alias; now `$branch` is unquoted, and will be expanded at the time you define the alias.

Comment: They are fixed now, but they probably don't do what you think. An empty quoted string can simply be removed. If you want to embed a literal single quote in a single-quoted string, that's `'\''` or `'"'"'`

Comment: @tripleee You are right. It technically didn't become empty string, rather a concatenation of two single quoted strings. But in the end it hadn't had any effect anyway. I used `'\''` as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea that the `"` resolved immediately upon Bash launch as opposed to using `'`. The function is also a much better choice to avoid the quote escaping mess. I learned so much today :)